# Is it possible to add query parameters to url before refreshing a page?

Tags: javascript, url, page-refresh, html5-history, query-string

I have a URL with some query parameters, and I want to hide the query parameters from the users (to prettify the URL), so I do something like this:

```
function removeQueryParameters () {
    var newUrl = location.href.split("?")[0];
    queryParameters = location.href.split("?")[1];
    history.replaceState({}, document.title, newUrl);
}
```

This removes the parameters from the URL.

To be able to load the correct content when a user refreshes the page i have tried this:

```
function reattachQueryParameters () {
    var newUrl = queryParameters ? location.href + "?" + queryParameters : location.href;
    history.replaceState({}, document.title, newUrl);
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    reattatchQueryParameters();
}
```

But this does not work. onbeforeunload is called and location.href is getting updated but it will not refresh to the updated URL.

Is it possible to get this to work?

Comment: If you get this to work, won't it overwrite any URLs of links that the user intends to go to, instead of going to those links, since onbeforeunload is activated when a link is clicked too?

Comment: Good point, it would, so I would have to check that before I change the URL, but that should not be to hard to do.